What is the smallest bound cluster of Helium-3 atoms?
Helium-4 can form an extremely weak dimer. It is a barely-bound halo state in which most the molecule's wave-function is in the classically forbidden region.
Helium-3, however, has no dimer. (Edit): It is not due to it being a fermion, since atoms can pair with opposite spins. The only reason is because the atom is lighter. The Van Der Waals force falls off as inverse seventh and so there are no long-wavelength bound states. The potential well is simply too shallow and small to bind such a light pair of atoms.
But bulk helium-3 is bound, otherwise it wouldn't condense into a liquid. What is the  smallest bound cluster of Helium-3 atoms? Is it a halo state with much lower density than bulk Helium-3?
Note: Volume can be measured by measuring the position of each atom and placing a sphere there with the same volume as the per-atom volume in bulk Helium-3, and then computing a convex hull. Define density as mass / expected volume. Is this value much lower than bulk Helium-3?

Bulk helium 3 is not bound. If you put liquid helium 3 into  vacuum it will evaporate into individual atoms. Liquids exist only when they are in equilibrium with a vapour pressure greater than zero.

Have searched the web with term ’he3 cluster’?

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superfluid_helium-4 Helium-3, however, is a fermion particle, which can form bosons only by pairing with itself at much lower temperatures (2.5 mK)

@JohnRennie If bulk helium 3 is not bound, 'evaporation' makes no sense. It simply expands with zero heat of vaporization when released from a container to vacuum?

It doesn't seem likely the non-existence of $^3\mathrm{He}_2$ is due to $^3\mathrm{He}$ being a fermion as you'd expect both atoms to be able to share the same lowest energy state with their spins opposite. I wonder if it's because $^3\mathrm{He}$ is lighter than $^4\mathrm{He}$ and therefore would have a large zero point motion.

@JohnRennie Ineed, see https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms6765.

@JohnRennie: The vapor pressure of both He3 and He4 goes to zero at zero kelvin, as shown here:
https://faculty.sites.iastate.edu/canfield/files/inline-files/Physics%20590%20dilution.pdf
So it will stay bound in a vacuum chamber so long as it is cold enough. There is a tiny but non-zero 40 J/mol enthalpy of vaporization.

My point is just that it doesn't make sense to regard a bulk liquid as bound in the sense that a dimer is bound. There will certainly be a smallest stable drop size that is a trade off between the bulk interaction and the surface energy, but that isn't a quantum effect. Below this size the drop will evaporate as that lowers the total energy.

@JohnRennie: Besides Helium 3, are there other bulk substances that for which the dimer is unbound at zero Kelvin? I have heard of water dimer in the vapour phase at 300K so presumably it would form a bound states at low temperature.
